# pgfplots: draw extra tick after axis definition

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider the following MWE, where an example sine function is plotted:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
             xmin=-0.1, xmax=10.5,
             ymin=-1.9, ymax=1.9,
             axis lines=middle,
             x axis line style={name path=xaxis}]

    \addplot[name path global=plot1,domain=0:10, samples=101]{sin(deg(x))};

\path [draw,name intersections={of={plot1 and xaxis}}]
  (intersection-1) node (A) {}
  (intersection-2) node (B) {}
  (intersection-3) node (C) {}
  (intersection-4) node (D) {};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It determines the points where the plot intersects the x-axis and I can't run it before defining the axes. Is it possible to define extra ticks on the x-axis in these intersection points? If yes, how?

---

**Edit**: Of course, this question is related to not well-know functions, whose zeros can not be analytically determined and/or are not known *a priori*.

Comment: For a sine function you can determine the zeros analytically, and add the corresponding ticks. But I am assuming this question is about functions whose zeros you cannot determine analytically. Then, as far as I know, you cannot simply add ticks via keys in the axis. But you can still add them after you determined the intersections in a loop. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I don't know about loops, but yes, this question is about functions whose zeros can not be determined analytically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal that adds ticks in a loop. It computes the x coordinates of the intersections by normalizing them by the distance of 1 in axis units.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
             xmin=-0.1, xmax=10.5,
             ymin=-1.9, ymax=1.9,
             axis lines=middle,
             x axis line style={name path=xaxis},
             clip mode=individual]

    \addplot[name path global=plot1,domain=0:10, samples=101]{sin(deg(x))};

\path [draw,name intersections={of={plot1 and xaxis},total=\t}]
 let \p0=($(1,0)-(0,0)$) in
 foreach \X in {1,...,\t}
 {let  \p1=($(intersection-\X)-(0,0)$) in 
 ([yshift=2pt]intersection-\X) edge ([yshift=-2pt]intersection-\X) 
  node[above]{$\pgfmathparse{\x1/\x0}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$} };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously, if you know something about the function you can pretty-print the ticks by normalizing them on pi instead.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth,
             xmin=-0.1, xmax=10.5,
             ymin=-1.9, ymax=1.9,
             axis lines=middle,
             x axis line style={name path=xaxis},
             clip mode=individual]

    \addplot[name path global=plot1,domain=0:10, samples=101]{sin(deg(x))};

\path [draw,name intersections={of={plot1 and xaxis},total=\t}]
 let \p0=($(1,0)-(0,0)$) in
 foreach \X in {1,...,\t}
 {let  \p1=($(intersection-\X)-(0,0)$) in 
 ([yshift=2pt]intersection-\X) edge ([yshift=-2pt]intersection-\X) 
  node[above]{$\pgfmathparse{\x1/\x0/pi}\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt<0.1pt
  0
  \else
   \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt<1.1pt
    \pi
   \else
    \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult\pi
   \fi  
  \fi$} };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]